# What is the opposite of a "discrete set"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, definition

$\mathcal{N} = \{1, \ldots, p\}$ or $\{1, 2, 3, 4,\ldots\}$ are discrete sets.

So what is the opposite of a discrete set?

There is no such thing as a "continuous set".

I know there is convex set, connected sets as well as path connected sets and their generalizations.

Which concept would most appropriately or generally describe sets (such as $(a,b),[a,b]$ and their products, etc.) where there is no discontinuity when traveling from one point to another? i.e., what is the most general way to describe a "connected set?"

Comment: Define "opposite."

Comment: Do you have any particular context where you've seen this terminology? From your examples, it looks like someone might be using "discrete set" as short for "discrete linearly ordered set" as opposed to a densely ordered set, but without context it's hard to say.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No jumps going from one point to another.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine For example you want to define a discrete random variable versus a continuous random variable. The image of a discrete random variable is discrete versus a continous random variable which is..."continuous".

Comment: Discreteness is a property of a topology on a set, and not the set per se, so it would be better to phrase this question as, "What is the opposite of a discrete space?" Also, there are topologies in which $\Bbb{N}$ and $\{1, 2, ..., p \}$ are not discrete.

Comment: @Olórin: very similarly, in spectral theory there is the "pure point spectrum", which is a discrete set (well, kind of), and the "continuous spectrum".

Comment: Maybe a perfect set? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set)

Comment: "So what is the opposite of a discrete set?" A set that is not discrete?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why [connected set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), which you are already aware of, does not meet your needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *crowded space* is a $T_1$ space without isolated points. Such need not be connected of course. But it is sort of opposite of discrete in some ways.

I don't think there is a most general concept as you envisage. Path-connected comes close.

Answer (score 2):

A topological space is [discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) iff every point is an [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) iff every [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) is an open set. So you could say the opposite of a discrete space is one in which [every nonempty open set contains more than one point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself): a space which is **dense-in-itself**.

However, the nomenclature **indiscrete space** or **anti-discrete space** usually refers to a different concept, a space where the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and the entire space (i.e. it has the [trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology)). We might think of this type of space as the *polar* opposite of a discrete space, since in a discrete space, every subset is open.